# How do you "split" a data set apart in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is a very newbie question, but I actually don't know how to do this.
I have a data set which looks like this:

[image]

I want to expand it like so:

[image]

I would ideally like to do this with an Excel function, not manually. What can I do for this?

Comment: what version of Excel?

Comment: I haven't done this.  If I had to, I would explore the "ungroup" feature under "Data".  If your data set was formed by grouping, ungroup might be the easiest way to go.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to expand the frequency table in this way?

Answer (score 5):

If you have Excel 2016+ with the `CONCAT` function, you can use:

***Note:** As noted in the comments, this may require Excel O365 or Excel 2019+. I recall the function being available long before Excel 2019, but it was not available in the original 2016*

```
=MID(CONCAT(REPT(htTbl[Height]&",",htTbl[Count])),1,LEN(CONCAT(REPT(htTbl[Height]&",",htTbl[Count])))-1)
```

As pointed out by @ScottCraner in the comments, the formula can be shortened to:

```
=MID(CONCAT(REPT(","&htTbl[Height],htTbl[Count])),2,999)
```

*I used a Table with structured references, but you can change that to regular addressing if you prefer. An advantage of Tables, however, is that you don't need to change your formula if you add or delete rows from the table, as the references self-adjust.*

[image]

Comment: Good answer - just a minor comment that `CONCAT` is available from Excel 2019 onward and 365.  Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2

Comment: For 2016 version replace with “concatenate”

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 no, `CONCATENATE` does not accept arrays and is why `CONCAT` was created.

Comment: if you put the `,` first you do not need to repeat: `=MID(CONCAT(REPT(","&htTbl[Height],htTbl[Count])),2,999)`

Comment: @ScottCraner ok then it would require a string =...&REPT(F10,G10)&","&REPT(F11,G11)&","etc

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks. Will update.

Comment: @KennethL Thanks. Will add that caveat.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 `CONCATENATE` is not a 2016 substitute. Hard to make that kind of string dynamic to account for changes in the size of the table. Before `CONCAT`, frequent solutions included either helper column (or row), or VBA

Comment: Yes @RonRosenfeld , but this is a simpler case, I thought, so just rept ( , ) &

Answer (score 1):

You can try this formula:

```
=LEFT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,SUBSTITUTE(REPT(B3:B8,C3:C8),B3:B8,B3:B8&",")),LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,SUBSTITUTE(REPT(B3:B8,C3:C8),B3:B8,B3:B8&",")))-1)
```

It uses the functions:

- `REPT` to repeat the values
- `SUBSTITUTE` to replace the repeated values and to add the commas between them
- `TEXTJOIN` to concatenate all rows
- `LEN` and `LEFT` to get the length and extract the values

[image]

Comment: `TEXTJOIN` is a function available only to Excel 2019 and onwards, and to Excel 365.